# Having issues with getting usort to work in ASC order

Tags: php, usort

```
usort( $bla, function( $a, $b )
{
    return strcmp( $a->title, $b->title ); 
});
```

is returning my list in DESC order rather than ASC order... How would I go about tweaking this?

I tried:

```
usort( $bla, function( $a, $b )
{
    return ( strcmp( $a->title, $b->title ) < 0 ) ? $a->title : $b->title; 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reverse the arguments to `strcmp`.

```
usort( $bla, function( $a, $b )
{
    return strcmp( $b->title, $a->title ); 
});
```

Comment: Oh gawd, really.. that's not even funny.. Thanks brah <paint me embarrassed>